# Objects that are "unhidden" after checking a box don't go away when a different box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So here's the code I'm using to make it so any checkbox of a certain class can only have one option selected among the others with the same class.

```
$(function() {
$(".single-checkbox1").on("click", function() {
    $(".single-checkbox1").not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
});
```

Except, some of these checkboxes show objects when checked, like a text box or text area. The issue is that, unless you manually uncheck the box that shows the object before checking a different box, the object doesn't go away.

For example, if I checked box 1 to reveal textbox 1, then checked box 2 (the page then unchecks box 1 as only one box is allowed to be checked,) the textbox 1 will not disappear.

However, if I manually uncheck box 1 before checking box 2, textbox 1 WILL disappear. Has anyone encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use radio buttons instead? Radio buttons in a group only allow one button to be checked at a time. You can do a change event or .each on the group and based on the checked property, you can hide or show the appropriate check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

How do you show/hide the objects when a checkbox is (un)checked? Is it in another *on click* handler?

If so, I think `$(".single-checkbox1").prop("checked", false)` only unchecks the checkbox but doesn't call its handler (so the object will not show/hide). It may be better to do something like:

```
$(".single-checkbox1").on("click", function() {
    $(".single-checkbox1:checked").not(this).click();

    // If it's a different handler, do
    // $(".single-checkbox1:checked").not(this).trigger('whateverHandler');

    // If this doesn't uncheck the box then do this instead
    // $(".single-checkbox1:checked").not(this).prop("checked", false).click();
});
```

Create a plunker or snippet if none of this helps and we can try other solutions.